# Compare 2 CSV files, output to 3rd file with combined data

Tags: bash, list, csv, compare

I posted earlier but made some changes since then and the format has changed quite a bit so starting the question again to suit the new format.

I have 2 csv spreadsheets, each with 2 columns. They are in the following format:

```
File1.csv

string,Value

string1,4

string2,5

string3,6

string4,7

string5,8

string6,9
```

And then the second file is;

```
File2.csv

string,Value

string4,8

string5,7

string1,3

string2,7

string3,4  

string7,5
```

Note that the orders are random in both files. There will also be entries in file1 that not present within file2, notice how sting6 is only in file1.

What i would like to do is use Bash (or python if that's easier) to look through file 1, find the same string in file 2 and then output this to a third file with the values side by side for example:

```
output.csv
string1,4,3
string2,5,7
string3,6,4
string4,7,8
string5,9,7
string6,9,  
string7,,5
```

again, notice string 6 is present but no comparison.

I have tried the following but with no luck;

```
#!/bin/bash  
awk  'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","}  
        NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}   
        FNR==1  {print $1,$2"1",a[$1]"2"; next}   
                {print $1,$2,a[$1]}' File1.csv File2.csv
```

When I run this I get some odd output like this:

```
4tring,4  
,3string2,5  
,7string3,6  
,4string4
```

Happy to try other methods if this isn't the best.

Comment: is this line `string,Value` always present in each file(as the first one)?

Comment: yeah, exactly the same

Comment: @snowblind don't ask a new question for the same problem. If do you think, that the close is wrong - please add more details in what this question is different from the linked one... By me, it is the SAME question.

Comment: `string5,9,7` - should be `string5,8,7`(to be precise)

Answer (score 0):

In awk

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                # set delimiters
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$2; next }          # hash first file
{ print $1,a[$1],$2; delete a[$1] } # output second file matches and non-matches
END { for(i in a) print i,a[i] }    # output leftovers from file 1
' file1 file2                       # mind the order
string,Value,Value
string4,7,8
string5,8,7
string1,4,3
string2,5,7
string3,6,4  
string7,,5
string6,9
```